# The json formatted response from django API with serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have been trying to get the response as given below but am a little stuck as to how to achieve it..
I tried other ways without serializers but then my pagination does not work as expected..

the question for the pagination issue is
[Pagination does not seem to be working using get method and APIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75095180/pagination-does-not-seem-to-be-working-in-django-rest-api-with-get-method)

below is my dataset:

```
    data = [['1','2023-01-04 12:39','{"kpiThreshold": 23, "kpiValue": 25, "kpiDiff": 2}'],
        ['2','2023-01-03 12:39','{"kpiThreshold": 23, "kpiValue": 26, "kpiDiff": 3}'],
        ['1','2023-01-02 12:39','{"kpiThreshold": 23, "kpiValue": 27, "kpiDiff": 4}']]
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'date','kpi'])
    df_new
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from pegaapi.models import PegaAlerts

class AlertsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PegaAlerts
        fields = ('id','generateddatetime','kpiValues')
```

views.py

```
class FullLogsAPI(GenericAPIView):
    pagination_class=CustomPagination
    serializer_class = AlertsSerializer
    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        envid = self.kwargs.get('envid')
        nodeid = self.kwargs.get('nodeid')
        startdatetime = self.request.GET.get('startdatetime')
        enddatetime = self.request.GET.get('enddatetime')
        filter_list=PegaAlerts.objects.filter(envId=envid, serverId=nodeid, generateddatetime__lte=enddatetime, generateddatetime__gte=startdatetime,).order_by('generateddatetime')
        page = self.paginate_queryset(filter_list)
        serializer = AlertsSerializer(page, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Response :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "generateddatetime": "2023-01-04 12:39",
        "kpiValues": "{\"kpiThreshold\": 23, \"kpiValue\": 25, \"kpiDiff\": 2}"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "generateddatetime": "2023-01-03 12:39",
        "kpiValues": "{\"kpiThreshold\": 23, \"kpiValue\": 26, \"kpiDiff\": 3}"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "generateddatetime": "2023-01-02 12:39",
        "kpiValues": "{\"kpiThreshold\": 23, \"kpiValue\": 27, \"kpiDiff\": 4}"
    }
]
```

But the response i'm looking for is

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "generateddatetime": "2023-01-04 12:39",
            "kpiValues": {
                          "kpiThreshold": 23,
                          "kpiValue": 25,
                          "kpiDiff": 2
                         }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "generateddatetime": "2023-01-03 12:39",
            "kpiValues": {
                          "kpiThreshold": 23,
                          "kpiValue": 26,
                          "kpiDiff": 3
                         }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "generateddatetime": "2023-01-02 12:39",
            "kpiValues": {
                          "kpiThreshold": 23,
                          "kpiValue": 27,
                          "kpiDiff": 4
                         }
        }
    ]
```

Any pointers or suggestions how i can achieve the same ?

Comment: In PegaAlerts model what is the type of KPIValues field ?

Comment: kpiValues = models.TextField(null=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your serializer and try this,

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from pegaapi.models import PegaAlerts
import json 

class AlertsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    kpiValues = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_kpiValues(self, obj):
        return json.loads(obj.kpiValues)

    class Meta:
        model = PegaAlerts
        fields = ('id','generateddatetime','kpiValues')
```

Comment: cheers.. its worked for most of the data but what if the kpivalues column has "NaN" or null values. I get an error "ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant"

Comment: So you have to replace NaN values in your dataframe, eg.:

df = df.fillna('')

Comment: If the solution worked you can make the answer accepted.